# C# Atlassian Jira library not working with Users since GDPR

Tags: c#, .net, jira

using NET6 framework with [Atlassian.Jira 13.0.0](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/docs/change-history.md)
My Problem is that I can't assign a reporter, when trying to create a new issue, because the "old" style with username is deprecated because auf GDPR strict mode.

Assigning the AccountId don't work and Searching for User isn't working any more, too.

[image]

```
: 'Response Status Code: 400. Response Content: {"errorMessages":["The query parameter 'username' is not supported in GDPR strict mode."],"errors":{}}'
```

The documentation don't seems to handle user assignments (without using username).

Now the question is if I can (and how) use the Library.

Comment: Search isn't working, too: "The query parameter 'username' is not supported in GDPR strict mode"

Comment: Also not possible to assign ReporterUser directy: "public JiraUser ReporterUser { get; private set; }"